# Android studio suspended on indexing

Tags: android-studio, gradle

When i run android studio it freeze on indexing and show me message:

[image]

indexing suspended (context: Gradle Sync)

it take more then 42 min and still show me this message i can't stop process and almost every thing is disable

**Solutions I've tried**

1- enable offline mode

2- select local gradle

3- invalidate caches/ Restart

but no one of this is solve my problem .

Comment: what versions of AS and Gradle are used?

Comment: AS: 3.1 Canary 2 Gradle version is 4.4-20171031235950+0000

Comment: please take a thread dump and post an issue to Android Studio team here https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html

Comment: Sometimes happens with as3.0.1 to me, tries as3.1 canary 6 without luck (but a more explicit message: Indexing suspended (context: Project Setup))

Comment: when i update android studio it work fine . thank you for help

Comment: same problem on 3.1.0 stable

Comment: same problem on 3.1.2 stable

Answer (score 26):

I've solved closing project (Menu File -> Close Project) and reopening it selecting his build.gradle.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case, syncing the project with file system helped. But the project uses react-native and many gradle modules are located in the node_modules folder which could be updated by yarn/npm.