# Android studio suspended on indexing gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When i open my project in Android Studio, then it freezes with this message.

[image]

> indexing suspended (context: Gradle Sync)

It has been 1 hour and i can not do anything. **Even i can not stop process, just i can close project.**

I have tried.

1- enable/disable offline mode

2- delete .gradle inside users, app folder and android studio folder.

3- invalidate caches/ Restart

Tried also this answer and some others.

[Android studio suspended on indexing gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422883/android-studio-suspended-on-indexing-gradle/50423005#50423005)

Some one who solved this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588765/android-studio-suspended-on-indexing

Comment: @NileshRathod Tried already before asking question

Comment: @Khemraj Any solution?

Comment: I don't know why this happen, try deleting .idea folder then reopening project.